# PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod - An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: windows, powershell, tls1.2

I'm trying to send a simple get request from Windows 10 PowerShell but I'm always getting an error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod https://myiseserver/admin/API/mnt/Session/MACAddress/B8:3B:CC:50:BA:B6 -Credential $cred
Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

I was trying to enable TLS in many different ways but the error is always the same. I was trying this:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

and this

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

When I'm doing exactly same thing using original CURL (not the PS alias) everything is working perfectly fine.

I noticed that when I set TLS1.3 I'm getting a different error

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls13
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://myiseserver/admin/API/mnt/Session/MACAddress/B8:3B:CC:50:BA:B6 -Credential $cred
Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
```

I was also trying different resources like https://google.com and 3 different Windows 10 computers but the effect was the same - error occured on a send.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved recently similar issue with PowerShell in Windows server 2022.

In my case it was caused by a proxy being turned off for that one user who actually is running the script.

Note that I was not calling external site as the site I was calling from PowerShell was hosted in IIS in the same server, but still that PowerShell command requires proxy to be turned on.

To turn on proxy:
Go to Internet Explorer browser > Settings symbol > "Internet Options" > "Connections" tab > "Lan settings"

Mark two below check boxes and enter valid proxy and port.

Note that these options are per user basis - if you set it for one system account another one may not have it configured.

[Proxy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBUSQ.png)